# Communicating with AWS KMS in Laravel?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am looking into setting up KMS with Laravel and have hit a wall in trying to figure out how to start communicating with KMS. I have been looking through the documentation and am initially trying to set up my client, but I am uncertain what I need to pass into my factory.

```
$kmsClient = \Aws\Kms\KmsClient::factory([/*what goes in here???*/]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory array wants to get array of configuration options

AWS KMS configuration options are described here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/configuration.html#client-configuration-options

You need to have Amazon account where you can get all required values.